# Select File APDU command failing with MiFare 1k card

Tags: c#, smartcard, mifare, pcsc, winscard

I'm using [PCSC-Sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) to transmit commands to a card. The specific command is:

> 00 A4 04 0C 0C D2 76 00 01 35 4B 41 4E 4D 30 31 00 00

So I did the following:

```
var contextFactory = ContextFactory.Instance;
using (var ctx = contextFactory.Establish(SCardScope.System)) {
    using (var isoReader = new IsoReader(ctx, readerName, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any, false)) {

        var apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case4Short, isoReader.ActiveProtocol) {
            CLA = 0x00,
            Instruction = InstructionCode.SelectFile, //0xA4
            P1 = 0x04,
            P2 = 0x0C,
            Data = new byte[] { 0x0C, 0xD2, 0x76, 0x00, 0x01, 0x35,
                        0x4B, 0x41, 0x4E, 0x4D, 0x30, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00 },
            Le = 0x00,
        };

        var response = isoReader.Transmit(apdu);
        Console.WriteLine("SW1 SW2 = {0:X2} {1:X2}", response.SW1, response.SW2);
    }
}
```

But on `Transmit` an `InvalidApduException` is thrown on getting `SW1`.

Am I missing something when converting the command string into a `CommandApdu` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mifare cards have no file system (just some numbered sectors) and understand no ISO 7816-4 APDUs, so InvalidApduException seems correct. The readers, which are able to handle MIFARE typically understand some pseudo-APDUs (CLA=0xFF, ...) which are translated accordingly. While these depend on the respective reader, some pretty established conventions exist, which you should find easily here using the [mifare](/questions/tagged/mifare) tag.

The SELECT by AID (for file-system based cards) or SELECT application (for Javacards) you are attempting is unlikely to have such a direct translation, since MIFARE cards have no similar concept.